# Eclipse: use Struts Actions of imported Project

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, import, action

I have 2 Dynamic Web Projects:

- cms
- Demo

Using Struts2 I want project Demo to use actions of the project CMS.

In Demo's "Java Build Path" configuration, in the "Project" tab I added the CMS project.

[image]

Now in the `struts.xml` of Demo I have

```
<action name="hello" class="cms.helloworld.action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
```

where the package `cms.helloworld.action` is a CMS project package.

[image]

Eclipse see it correctly, in fact with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> click on the class name it open me the correct Java file.

Now, in Demo's deployment assembly configuration I added the CMS project, so that also Tomcat can find the relative classes.

[image]

But when I run the project on tomcat server the log says:

> Grave: Dispatcher initialization failed
>   Unable to load configuration. - action
>
> Caused by: Action class [cms.helloworld.action.HelloWorldAction] not found

It can't find the action on CMS project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A more pertinent question might be "What am I not doing wrong?". First, you should add the _compiled_ classes from your CMS project to Demo as a `jar` file. And second you should add them to the classpath and not the buildpath.

Comment: And how do I add compiled class from CMS to Demo as a jar file? In web deployment assembly Eclipse creates a .war and put it in web-inf/lib of Demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge two projects into one, and put `struts.xml` into `src`. As far as I remember Eclipse is not able to reference another web project as module, i.e. you have to copy `WebContent` manually during build, that is why you shouldn't reference other web projects and a main project is not a Java EE project. You should also take into account that Tomcat server is not able to handle Java EE projects if you decide to develop one, for this purpose you should choose full featured Java EE Application server. Even that you have an option to only one web module.

Comment: There are certain JavaEE features that Tomcat doesn't support, I very much doubt the OP is going to have need of JMS or JTA...

Comment: Yes I'd like to use EJB and Glassfish but what I'm developing is a very small application and I can only afford java hosting with Tomcat. I can't merge the two project into one... the all point is that the business logic is in CMS and in future I'll develop many other "Demo" using always the same Cms resources. If I understand you correctly I have to build with ant and manually import cms src into demo. But really Eclipse do not provide this automatically? web deployment assembly is there to do that, but it creates me a .war file instead of .jar

Comment: @SimoneConti Eclipse not using `ant` to build your project, it uses project builders configured to your project. But you could run `ant` in eclipse. If your project is a Dynamic Web Project then it could assembly a `war` or `war exploded` depends on eclipse product. If you want to create a `jar` you should create a Java Project and build it as `jar`.

Comment: And ofcourse you can't use EJB with Tomcat, you need Glassfish or TomEE server.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, but OP didn't tell about his needs in the question, but it seems he is trying to build Java EE Project, anyway he can't have two dynamic web projects in the same application.

Comment: At the end I solved this by making CMS a Java project instead of Dynamic Web Project. In this way the Deployment Assembly imported me a jar instead of a war and Tomcat finally found action classes.